# How to handle global logging in Python when (some) classes need to be pickled

Tags: python, logging, pickle

I have a question about logging in Python. The situation is as follows: I have a global context object (singleton) for my application which - amongst other things - holds a logger object. All classes that need to use logging can get this global logger object from the context and use it to output messages.

However, some objects that hold such the logger need to get saved to a pickle file. Saving to pickles does not work when the pickled objects have a reference to an open FileHandler, which is the case for objects in this case, because they hold the logger and consequently an open file handler.

Now, I could remove all file handlers before pickling, like this:

```
def closeLogFile(self):
    handlers = self.logger.handlers[:]
    for handler in handlers:
        handler.close()
        self.logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

But this has the side effect that the log handlers are removed also for all other objects that still hold a reference to the global logger.

What would be a better way to both allow global logging to the same file and allow pickling of individual classes?

Thanks a million in advance.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dill` instead of `pickle`, it might work for you.  `dill` can handle references to `FileHandles`, and has variants to suite different use cases.  Here's the default:

```
>>> import dill
>>> import logging
>>> l = logging.Logger('foo')
>>>
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.logger = l
...     self.x = x
...     self.other = logging.Logger('bar')
... 
>>> f = Foo(4)
>>> f.logger
<logging.Logger object at 0x1094d3210>
>>> f.other
<logging.Logger object at 0x1094d34d0>
>>>
>>> f_ = dill.dumps(f)
>>> _f = dill.loads(f_)
>>> 
>>> _f.logger
<logging.Logger object at 0x1094f1c90>
>>> _f.other
<logging.Logger object at 0x1094f1b50>
```

Note the unpicked `Logger` instances are different instances than the original instances, but they still point to the same log.  You actually get a new class `__main__.Foo`, because `dill` pickles the class object instead of pickling the reference, by default. This behavior should extend to different classes -- as essentially the old `__main__.Foo` and the new `__main__.Foo` already demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks so much, Mike. This works perfectly. I'll be using dill instead of pickle. Just to to the answer: In order to save to a specific file path, this syntax should be used:     with open(path, "wb") as f:
        dill.dump(clf, f)

Comment: Cool.  Yeah, `dill` uses the same syntax for `dump` and `dumps`  as `pickle` does, although `dill` has a few additional options for special handling of files and classes.